# Bind different docker container paths to single named volume

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a dockerized app which has two interesting directories that I want to access. I'm using named volumes.

```
version: "3.7"
services
  myapp:
    volumes:
      - myvol1:/foo/data
      - myvol2:/bar/data
volumes
  myvol1:
  myvol2:
```

Which gives:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/
  myvol1/_data/
    ...stuff from container's /foo/data
  myvol2/_data/
    ...stuff from container's /bar/data
```

This is a hassle to maintain, so I'd rather use a single volume for both:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol/_data/
  foo
    ...stuff from container's /foo/data
  bar
    ...stuff from container's /bar/data
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `driver_opts` to get the named volume mount to other place. A minimal workable example as next for your reference:

**Step 1: Prepare folders:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ cd /tmp
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:/tmp$ mkdir bar foo
```

**Steps 2: Specify driver_opts to use `/tmp/foo` & `/tmp/bar` as the target mounted location:**

***docker-compose.yaml:***

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myapp:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - myvol1:/etc
      - myvol2:/bin
volumes:
  myvol1:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/tmp/foo'
  myvol2:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/tmp/bar'
```

***execute it:***

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/test_dir$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "test_dir_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "test_dir_myvol1" with local driver
Creating volume "test_dir_myvol2" with local driver
Creating test_dir_myapp_1 ... done
```

**Steps 3: Test if things work:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/test_dir$ ls /tmp/foo
alpine-release  crontabs  hostname  inittab  modprobe.d  motd opt periodic   protocolsservices  ssl  udhcpd.conf
apk fstab hosts issuemodules mtab os-release  profileresolv.conf  shadowsysctl.conf
conf.d  group init.dlogrotate.d  modules-load.d  network  passwd  profile.d  securettyshellssysctl.d
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/test_dir$ ls /tmp/bar
arch  chgrp   dd ed   fsync ionicelinux32  makemime  mountpoint  ping   reformime  setprivsu  uname
ash   chmod   df egrepgetoptiostatlinux64  mkdir mpstat  ping6  revsetserial  syncusleep
base64chown   dmesg  falsegrep  ipcalcln   mknod mv  pipe_progress  rm sh tar watch
bbconfig  conspy  dnsdomainname  fatattr  gunzipkbd_mode  loginmktempnetstat printenv   rmdir  sleep  touch   zcat
busybox   cp  dumpkmap   fdflush  gzip  kill  ls   more  niceps run-parts  stat   true
cat   dateecho   fgrephostname  link  lzop mount pidof   pwdsedstty   umount
```

You can see the `/etc` & `/bin` which in alpine already could be seen in `/tmp/foo` & `/tmp/bar`.

Comment: Thanks! However this still uses two volumes. I'm interesting to know how to do it with one volume.

Comment: I guess it's not easy for docker to distinguish `myvol:/foo/data` & `myvol:/bar/data`. As a common tool, seems no chance to understand the difference happens on `/foo/` & `/bar/`. Anyway you can wait to see if other folks can give good suggestion, good luck.

Comment: If it's not possible, I'll mark this as the answer... Thanks again!